# Typical HDD visualizations and misinformation. - Does air exist inside an HDD ? How many R/W heads do they contain?

Tags: hard-drive

Searching educational videos about the inner workings of a classic HDD to present in my classroom (I'm a teacher), I've come across some conflicting information.

I was taught that inside an HDD case there is vacuum. Some sources seem to support this by saying the actuator benefits from it as the lack of friction makes it much faster.

On the other hand other sources mention there is air inside the HDD case and although I know these are being made in a totally sterilized from particles environment, some can even contain a small filter inside the case to catch particles that may trap inside. Sources claiming the presence of air inside the case mention that the actuator actually benefits from it because it creates a cushion of air underneath it due to the great speed of the disc itself, thus preventing the head from crushing on it. For me this explanation is somewhat hard to believe because it quickly becomes questionable. For example, if spinning makes the arms lift-off then this implies that when the drive looses power before the arms retract (power cut-off) they can actually land on the disc posing serious threat when re-powering. We also know that the arms retract away from the disc when the OS is shutting down, so when the computer starts operating again, the arm must enter the disc area already in lift, but how will the lift take place if not already on the spinning disc ?

Which of the above is actually true? Could it be that both can be true depending the brand or way of manufacturing?

One more conflicting information I've come across is about the number of actuator arms on a HDD.

Some schematics present it with one arm, some with two (one reading the disc from above and one from below) and some with 3 or more arms making it look like a jukebox. What is true about that?

[image: schematic with many arms]

Comment: Hard drives I have taken apart (dead) do not have a vacuum inside.  The number of heads depends on the number of platters .

Comment: Most drives actually have a filtered air port. Some newer drives are hermetically sealed, but have helium inside for various reasons

Answer (score 7):

> I was taught that inside an HDD case there is vacuum.

No vacuum, hard drives rely on some gas (just air or (sealed) helium for example) to create an 'air'-bearing for the heads so they do not touch the surface.

> For me this explanation is somewhat hard to believe because it quickly
> becomes questionable. For example, if spinning makes the arms lift-off
> then this implies that when the drive looses power before the arms
> retract (power cut-off) they can actually land on the disc posing
> serious threat when re-powering.

Well, head crashes are a thing, but AFAIK hard drives autopark the heads when sudden loss of power occurs, or raise heads slightly to prevent touching the surface. Hard drives can also limit time the heads are over the surface, so park when there's no read/write activity. But there's always the risk of damage in case of sudden power loss, physical as well as logical. And even though SSD's don't have moving parts, sudden power loss can be harmful for those too.

This more an engineering problem that an obstacle that can not be overcome. I am not an engineer or mechanic, but a few decades ago I worked on my own air cooled VolksWagen and I remember several vacuum and relay operated feedback systems being in let's say 'safe mode' or not engaged in absence of vacuum or current, or for example the fuel pump being disengaged in case of certain (accident like) scenarios. I just mean to say, while you and I may not be able to see the solution to a problem does not mean there's no such solution.

> Some schematics present it with one arm, some with two (one reading
> the disc from above and one from below) and some with 3 or more arms
> making it look like a jukebox. What is true about that?

All options you mention, actually. Normally one platter = 2 arms, 2 platters = 4 arms however in case of 2 platters a manufacturer can limit capacity by leaving one arm out. These aren't conflicting examples, they're just different configurations.

This has been like this for a long time, and if we jump a few decades back, before CHS addresses were 'abstracted', to read a specific sector you would need to provide a cylinder / head / sector address. A few tools still mention CHS addresses and geometry, for example the open source too [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

If I were you I'd buy a hard drive on eBay or two perhaps in case you kill one, remove the lid and see what happens when powered on. Also, rather than gracefully shut it down, pull the connector to emulate sudden power loss and see if heads move to parking position. It also makes for a nice demonstration in class. Note that you will not be able to use this drive reliably after the experiments due to it being contaminated but more importantly the absence of the afore mentioned air bearing (which requires the lid to be in place by design).

Side note..

I wonder why the use of terms like 'misinformation', 'questionable', 'conflicting information'..